# Assign response string to webbrowser control in c# for smart phone

Tags: c#, string, request, browser, response

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.de");
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse1 =(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest1.GetResponse();
using (Stream stream = myHttpWebResponse1.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Get the response stream  
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

                    // Read the response into a string 
                    _responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    webBrowser1.DocumentText = _responseString;          
                }

webBrowser1.DocumentText = _responseString;
```

Hey!
In this code, I sent a request, and get the response. I read the response into a string, and after it I assign this string to the webbrowser control.
If i save the response string, I get pretty the same site, but when I assign it to the webbrowser control, it looks different.

Is there any way to assing the string to the webbrowser, and that show the same site, like in the saved file?

Comment: "It looks different"... In what way? If you can see what's different then you can probably figure out what is wrong/missing.

Comment: In the first picture, nothing are on the right place
http://imageshack.us/a/img812/6170/snap025t.png

If I save as a html, it's pretty good.
http://imageshack.us/a/img41/5610/snap026v.png

Comment: That has to do with the browser in the phone incapable of rendering the HTML as intended. The HTML/CSS is not generated for a phones browser but rather an ordinary browser.

Comment: But if I simply open the site on the phone, everything is perfect.
Only the response string generate this problem, or it's dosn't metter, and I should do some research for css?

Comment: When you go to the URL with the phones browser the server generates HTML/CSS specific for that browser. You need to find out what `User Agent` the phones browser provides and apply that in your code. Only then should you get the "correct" result.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I hope I can fine something, how can I solve this ccs problem.